# Could there be an alternative approach to questions with weak English?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, editor

Suppose I ask a question in poor English on date A and someone edits the question to make it understandable on date B. What if the difference between dates A and B is more than a week? Generally, questions appear on SO because of an urgent need and a delay in receiving an answer is not affordable.

Can't there be an approach built in that can make the question readable when initially asked? After all, weak English does not mean less knowledgeable.

For example, before posting a question, an asker may be given a choice to share their question with other users to make it understandable. In return we can provide the editors badges or reputation.

Comment: So you're suggesting that we  pre-edit / approve your questions? Nope, what's in that for us?

Comment: @Paulie_D According to the question? Badges and/or reputation.

Comment: SO was founded on the idea that a question never "expires".  Editing it re-activates it and sometimes it gets artificially reactivated by the Community user.  That was a decent idea 8 years ago, at the current rate of well over a quarter of a million questions per month with about half of them never getting an answer it is not exactly so practical anymore :)  If it matters then the OP can always put a bounty on it.

Comment: Done that...got them.

Comment: The point of the site is sharing, preserving, and collecting knowledge in one place, not providing free solutions to everyone's work questions... I am all for helping people but I think it may encourage low quality questions if people know they can then have someone else make it better for them.

Comment: *"Questions...appears on stack because of the need of an urgent answer and delay or gap is not affordable"* - if you need answers urgently, **pay for them**. As usual, pick any two of high quality, fast and cheap.

Comment: Cross site dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue

Answer (score 10):

> Generally, Questions (especially on Codes and Technical area) appears on stack because of the need of an urgent answer and delay or gap is not affordable.

If a question is urgent and you can't afford any delay in getting an answer, then you should take it to a co-worker, or consider hiring someone to help you work it out. Stack Overflow is for sharing knowledge in the *long* term, not providing quick support in the short term. The benefit of building a knowledge repository like Stack Overflow is that millions of people can get immediate answers to their questions through a simple Google search. That's because millions of questions have already been answered here, *not* because people are on-call to immediately answer urgent support requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can already ask for people to improve the English of your post (if they can) by adding a comment. Especially if the post is not too long, there will usually be someone to comply.

> Generally, Questions (especially on Codes and Technical area) appears on stack because of the need of an urgent answer and delay or gap is not affordable.

That might be true, but we're also here to help *future* visitors with the same problem. They also benefit from a question (and answers) which are worded in clear English.

Comment: You should not be asking people to edit your question in your question.  Questions are where you ask your quesiton, and should not include meta commentary on the question.  People also don't need to be told that they can fix the question if they see problems with it.  Editors already know that they can edit any quesiton that they see problems with it, if they want to.